# How can I use the USB block erupters to mine Namecoin?

Tags: asic, cgminer, namecoin, miner-configuration

Since the block erupter is useless to mine for Bitcoin now. From what I understand the only other two options would be is to mine Namecoin or Devcoin since they use SHA256 encryption. But how can I mine these? Would `cgminer` work? or is there another app that i need to use?

Also are Namecoin and Devcoin the only ones that use SHA256?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you can mine any altcoin that uses double-SHA256 hashing algorithm as a proof of work with any ASIC device. The process should be similar to mining Bitcoin - you would most likely want to connect to a mining pool or solo mine in a configuration analogous to mining Bitcoin.

Also note that Namecoin supports merged mining, meaning that if you mine for a Bitcoin block through a pool that supports merged mining, your proof of work can still be used to create Namecoin blocks. This effectively makes you mine for both currencies with the same amount of hashing power, increasing your expected return rate by the amount of other coin mined (so instead of mining just Namecoin, you would be getting some extra BTC kickback as well for your submitted shares).

Comment: thanks for the info, i tried looking online for any namecoin pools or how to go about doing it such as what program to use etc and came out empty. Would you know where i can start looking into it?

Comment: @Exploit I don't know. I think most people are merged mining instead.

Comment: The question was not if it were possible, but how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Bitminter does merged mining with Bitcoin and Namecoin. Pretty easy java interface client if you like - but i still prefer cgminer myself (for GPU mining)